# Launched Effect with delay Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

```
var currentTimeInMs by remember {
    mutableStateOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    while (true) {
        delay(200)
        currentTimeInMs = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

```
var currentTimeInMs by remember {
    mutableStateOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    while (true) {
        currentTimeInMs = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

In first code the value is updated every 200ms but in second code (without delay) value is not updated, I want to know why? My knowledge is that if we give key1 as true (constant) then LaunchedEffect only runs one time so in both the cases value should be updated once OR if I remain in while loop(in 2nd case), then value should be updated always

Comment: If I had to guess, your `LaunchedEffect` coroutine in the second version is never actually suspending, so there's no time for Compose to do anything else (including updating the UI). You could determine this is the case if the UI becomes unresponsive.

Comment: "in both the cases value should be updated once" is wrong, btw. The coroutine will only *run* once (per invocation). `while(true)` will still run indefinitely, obviously.

Comment: @Jorn that what i was about to say the launched effect runs once but the while loop will never stop

Comment: In second case(without delay) the application is crashing